# what happens when a nonexistent element of an array is reference in PERL?

Tags: arrays, perl

I just came through *de-referencing* in Perl..
but what will happen when we referred an Array when there is a nonexistent element

Comment: could you show a small code example of what you mean? It's a bit unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Not much. Every array has nonexistent elements.

Comment: i need what will be happened when there is no element while we are referencing in an array in PERL

Answer (score 1):

When you request a non-existent element from an array, you get `undef` back.

Answer (score 1):

If an rvalue is required, undef is returned.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E'
    my @a;
    print(Dumper($x));
    print(Dumper(\@a));
'
$VAR1 = undef;
$VAR1 = [];
```

If an lvalue is required, the array is extended, then the newly created but undefined element is returned.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E'
    my @a;
    print(Dumper($_)) for $a[4];
    print(Dumper(\@a));
'
$VAR1 = undef;
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef,
          undef
        ];
```

(Note that code gives subroutine parameters the rvalue behaviour unless you assign to `$_[0]`.)